# How to change the elements obj to alist in cl-mongo?

Tags: mongodb, common-lisp

The db.find will return the documents in MongoDB.

I want to get all the elements of the document and then change to alist.

But I have not found the function to get the elements.

I found elements is the hashmap in document, and it has a accessor called elements.

But when I use `(elements docTmp)` in my own package, it return that there is no function called elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not to go digging in the internals of the `document` but to use the provided function `mapdoc` . You can also consider the recursive parsing to convert the possible subdocuments to alists too. So the code may look like this:

```
(defgeneric mongo-document->alist (doc))

(defmethod mongo-document->alist ((doc cl-mongo:document))
  (let ((alist '()))
    (cl-mongo:mapdoc (lambda (key value)
                       (push
                        (cons
                         key
                         (mongo-document->alist value))
                        alist))
                     doc)
    alist))

(defmethod mongo-document->alist ((obj t))
  obj)
```